# Iam getting "TypeError: Movie.getMovieList is not a function" every time i try to run a object method from a different module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, neo4j

I'am fairly new to JS and i'm making a movie recommendation web app using express and neo4j. I'am facing problems while running an object method for a route. 
Basically I've created a Genre object and invoking a method to get a list of popular movies by specific to that genre which i'm then forwarding to the views.

I'am using async and await to handle asynchronous calls, and I've tested every single module separately and they work as intended.

I have two classes relevant to this problem - Movie and Genre, and a route to handle requests.

Genre module:

```
const executeQuery = require('./db/Neo4jApi').executeQuery;
const Movie = require('./Movie');

module.exports = class Genre {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    async getPopularMovies(limit) {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH(:Genre { name: $name })<-[:IN_GENRE]-(m :Movie)<-[:RATED]-(:User)\
            WITH m.imdbId as imdbId, COUNT(*) AS Relevance\
            ORDER BY Relevance DESC\
            LIMIT $limit\
            RETURN collect(imdbId)',
            { name: this.name, limit }
        );

        return await Movie.getMovieList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    static getGenreList(names) {
        const genres = [];
        names.forEach(name => genres.push(new Genre(name)));
        return genres;
    }

    static async getAllGenres() {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (g:Genre) return collect (g.name)'
        );
        return Genre.getGenreList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    static async test() {
        const action = new Genre('Animation');
        console.log(await action.getPopularMovies(5));
        console.log(Genre.getGenreList(["Action", "Crime", "Thriller"]));
    }
}
```

Movie module:

```
const executeQuery = require('./db/Neo4jApi').executeQuery;
const Person = require('./Person');
const Genre = require('./Genre');

module.exports = class Movie {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    setPoster() {
        let poster_id = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.id.length; i++) {
            if (this.id[i] != '0') {
                poster_id = this.id.substring(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        this.poster = '/images/' + poster_id + '.jpg';
    }

    // set details of given imdbid to build object
    async getDetails() {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (m:Movie {imdbId : $id})\
             RETURN m.title, m.runtime, m.year, m.plot, m.poster',
            { id: this.id }
        );

        const fields = response.records[0]._fields;
        this.title = fields[0];
        this.runtime = fields[1].low;
        this.year = fields[2].low;
        this.plot = fields[3];
        this.setPoster();
    }

    // return list of movie objects corresponding the given list of imdbIds
    // THIS IS THE METHOD THAT IS NOT BEING RECOGNIZED
    static async getMovieList(ids) {
        const movies = [];
        ids.forEach(id => movies.push(new Movie(id)));
        for (const movie of movies) await movie.getDetails();

        return movies;
    }

    // return list of genres of movie
    async getGenre() {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (m:Movie {imdbId : $id})-[:IN_GENRE]->(g:Genre)\
            RETURN collect(g.name)',
            { id: this.id }
        );

        return Genre.getGenreList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    // returns average rating of movie (out of 5)
    async getAvgRating() {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (:Movie {imdbId : $id})<-[r:RATED]->(:User)\
            RETURN AVG(r.rating)',
            { id: this.id }
        );

        return response.records[0]._fields[0].toFixed(2);
    }

    // return director/s of movie
    async getDirector() {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (m:Movie {imdbId : $id})<-[:DIRECTED]-(d:Director)\
            RETURN collect(d.name)',
            { id: this.id }
        );

        return Person.getPersonList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    // returns cast of  movie
    async getCast() {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (m:Movie {imdbId : $id})<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)\
            RETURN collect(a.name)',
            { id: this.id }
        );

        return Person.getPersonList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    // returns movies similar to this movie
    async getSimilar(limit) {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (curr :Movie { imdbId: $id })-[:IN_GENRE]->(g:Genre)<-[:IN_GENRE]-(sim :Movie)\
            WITH curr, sim, COUNT(*) AS commonGenres\
            OPTIONAL MATCH(curr)<-[: DIRECTED]-(d:Director)-[:DIRECTED]-> (sim)\
            WITH curr, sim, commonGenres, COUNT(d) AS commonDirectors\
            OPTIONAL MATCH(curr)<-[: ACTED_IN]-(a: Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(sim)\
            WITH curr, sim, commonGenres, commonDirectors, COUNT(a) AS commonActors\
            WITH sim.imdbId AS id, (3 * commonGenres) + (5 * commonDirectors) + (2 * commonActors) AS Similarity\
            ORDER BY Similarity DESC\
            LIMIT $limit\
            RETURN collect(id)',
            { id: this.id, limit }
        );

        return await Movie.getMovieList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    // returns all time popular movie
    static async getPopularMovies(limit) {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (m :Movie)<-[:RATED]-(:User)\
            WITH m.imdbId as imdbId, COUNT(*) AS Relevance\
            ORDER BY Relevance DESC\
            LIMIT $limit\
            RETURN collect(imdbId)',
            { limit }
        );
        return await Movie.getMovieList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    // returns popular movies of given year
    static async getPopularMoviesByYear(year, limit) {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH(m :Movie {year : $year})<-[:RATED]-(:User)\
            WITH m.imdbId as imdbId, COUNT(*) AS Relevance\
            ORDER BY Relevance DESC\
            LIMIT $limit\
            RETURN collect(imdbId)',
            { year, limit }
        );
        return await Movie.getMovieList(response.records[0]._fields[0]);
    }

    static async getYears() {
        const response = await executeQuery(
            'MATCH (m:Movie)\
            WITH DISTINCT m.year AS year ORDER BY year DESC\
            RETURN COLLECT(year)'
        );
        return response.records[0]._fields[0];
    }

    static async test() {
    }
}
```

Route :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Genre = require('../models/Genre');
const Movie = require('../models/Movie');

// get popular movies by all genre
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const allGenrePopular = await Movie.getPopularMovies(25);
    const genres = await Genre.getAllGenres();
    res.render('genre-list', {
        title: 'All Genres',
        header: 'Popular Movies: All Genres',
        movies: allGenrePopular,
        genres
    });
});

// get popular movies by genre
router.get('/:genre?', async (req, res) => {
    const genre = new Genre(req.params.genre);
    const popularMovies = await genre.getPopularMovies(25);// error originated here
    const genres = await Genre.getAllGenres();
    res.render('genre-list', {
        title: `${genre.name}`,
        header: `Popular Movies: ${genre.name}`,
        movies: popularMovies,
        genres
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
(node:10272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Movie.getMovieList is not a function
    at Genre.getPopularMovies (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\project\newmd\models\Genre.js:19:28)    
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:10272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10272) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the 
Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The problem is originating in the getMovieList() function in movie module, but i've tested it seperately times and it works fine.

Any suggestion to improve my code is welcome.

Comment: Are you including it in those modules using the require statement like this? => `const Genre = require('../models/Genre'); const Movie = require('../models/Movie');`

Comment: yes i am importing, i just updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a circular dependency issue here, which means your `Genre` class requires the `Movie` class and vice versa.

Remove one inclusion which you feel is not necessary (either `Genre` inclusion from the `Movie` class (or) `Movie` inclusion form the `Genre` class) and this issue will be resolved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Thanks for the help, will try to resolve it.